# Interpreting this PCA plot for RNA-seq

Tags: r, rna-seq, deseq2, pca, batch-effects

I have RNA-seq from two sequencing batches; Lab technician says that he has run the RNA expression quantification two times in bathes 1 and 2 for example `tumor 1 in batch 1 and tumor 1 in batch 2 , normal 2 in batch1 and normal 2 in batch 2`. This is my design for DESeq2

```
> head(mycols)
        condition batch
N_1_305         N     1
N_1_310         N     1
N_1_337         N     1
N_1_353         N     1
T_1_305         T     1
T_1_310         T     1
> tail(mycols)
        condition batch
T_2_337         T     2
T_2_338         T     2
T_2_344         T     2
T_2_346         T     2
T_2_349         T     2
T_2_353         T     2
>
```

I got this PCA plot

[image]

And this is biplot of samples
[image]

In PCA plot I am seeing for instance 
, `T_1_337 (batch1) has been placed too close to T_2_337 (batch2)`

Then I used svd for detecting hidden batch

[image]

Does this mean that there is no big batch effect between experimental runs and I can concatenate the fastqs from both batches for each sample (technical replication) or collapse technical replicates afterwards?

Please help me to interpret these
Thank you

---

> EDITED

---

Sorry @Devon, I have 4 lanes for each samples (paired end) in each of experimental runs; For concatenating fastq files can I do like this ?

```
cat fastq1_lane1_batch1 fastq1_lane1_batch2 fastq1_lane2_batch1   fastq1_lane2_batch2  fastq1_lane3_batch1 fastq1_lane3_batch2 fastq1_lane4_batch1 fastq1_lane4_batch2  > fastq1  

cat fastq2_lane1_batch1 fastq2_lane1_batch2 fastq2_lane2_batch1   fastq2_lane2_batch2  fastq2_lane3_batch1 fastq2_lane3_batch2 fastq2_lane4_batch1 fastq2_lane4_batch2 > fastq2
```

Comment: Why do you want to collapse replicates? It's really good that you have replicates. Treat them as such.

Comment: She's talking about technical replicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can safely concatenate the technical replicates. Odds are good that these are even the same libraries just sequenced twice, so even labeling them as replicates is a bit of a stretch. As an aside, it would be surprising if you actually had a batch effect in a situation like this. You will commonly see sequencing facilities just sequence a given sample a second time if it didn't get the number of reads requested by the client to begin with. They then just have the client concatenate the files.

Comment: Sorry @Devon, I have 4 lanes for each samples (paired end) in each of experimental runs; For concatenating fastq files can I do like this ?                  cat          fastq1_lane1_batch1 fastq1_lane1_batch2 fastq1_lane2_batch1   fastq1_lane2_batch2  fastq1_lane3_batch1 fastq1_lane3_batch2 fastq1_lane4_batch1 fastq1_lane4_batch2                             fastq2_lane1_batch1 fastq2_lane1_batch2 fastq2_lane2_batch1   fastq2_lane2_batch2  fastq2_lane3_batch1 fastq2_lane3_batch2 fastq2_lane4_batch1 fastq2_lane4_batch2

Comment: @Fereshteh That's a different question, and one you can find answers to by searching this site or biostars. Please do not stretch people offering to help by piling on more questions.

Comment: Sorry @Devon I think this question relates to this post; Can I use technical replicates for gene differential expression analysis? For example I am only interested in tumour A and normal A , can I compare them by using batch1 and batch2 as my replications?

Comment: I think you know the answer to that is "no".

Answer (score 1):

Prepping the RNA on different days, or making Illumina libraries on different days, or having different technicians handle different samples; that can lead to batch effects. 
 Running samples on two different days does not cause a significant batch effect, as you can plainly see in your PCA.  You should just combine the fastqs.

Comment: Thank you @swbarnes2, now my question is can I compare only one tumour with its own matched normal sample to get differentially expressed genes for this pair by using experimental runs (technical replicates )? Design would be Tumour1_batch1 Tumour1_batch2 versus Normal1_batch1 Normal1_bacth2

Comment: @Fereshteh As you're well aware, new questions should be posted as such.